# Web API 2 attribute routing returning 404

Tags: asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I'm having trouble getting the Web API 2 attribute routing to work.
I've been trying everything I could find this whole evening but I can't find the problem.

What I want to achieve is the following:
Make a POST request to `http://localhost:xxxx/api/chat/joingroup/1234` to get to the following API call:

```
[Route("joingroup/{id}")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> JoinGroup(string id, string connectionID)
{
    await hubContext.Groups.Add(connectionID, id);

    return Ok(hubContext.Groups.ToString());

}
```

This keeps getting me a http 400 message.

```
{"message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:41021/api/chat/joingroup/123'.",
"messageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Chat' that matches the request."}
```

But sending a post to: `http://localhost:41021/api/chat/sendmessage/pm/123123` and also to `http://localhost:41021/api/chat/joingroup` gives me a 200

The chatcontroller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/chat")]
public class ChatController : ApiController
{
    IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
    [...]

    [Route("joingroup/{id}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> JoinGroup(string id, string connectionID)
    {
        await hubContext.Groups.Add(connectionID, id);

        return Ok(hubContext.Groups.ToString());

    }
```

HTTP POSTS to `http://localhost:xxxx/api/chat/sendmessage` are working fine.
I cannot figure out why it isn't going to the correct method when I'm calling a POST on `http://localhost:xxxx/api/chat/joingroup/1234`.

**SOLUTION:**
The solution was to reference both values that are needed in the JoinGroup method, id and connectionID. Now the request will hit this method.
Using:
`http://localhost:xxxx/api/chat/joingroup/john?connectionid=123` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed two things on the code you sent through:

1. the path you POST to is:     localhost:xxxx/joingroup/1234    , this
   should be     localhost:xxxx/api/chat/joingroup/1234
2. because you have 2 parameters for the joingroup, you will need to pass both of them through, may be like this     localhost:xxxx/api/chat/joingroup/1234?connectionID=value  or you can pass it on the request body

if the connectionID is optional you can modify the method to use option al parameters like this

```
public  string JoinGroup(string id, string connectionID = "")
```

please let me know if this helps.
Thanks
Ashraf

Answer (score 1):

I assume the `connectionID` parameter references the POSTed data. The easiest thing to make it work is to decorate it with the `[FromBody]` attribute and put an `=` in front of the value being sent like this: `=MyConnection1`.

Web API expects an object with properties or an array otherwise. Alternatively, you can wrap the connection ID with a custom class and pass it serialized as JSON/XML.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I'm thinking of just sending a json to the method and let it work with a model.